# Benefits and detriments of multiple MySQL DB connections

Tags: mysql, security, database-design

Working on an application for a client that I've organized into two db's, one for public access and one for backend calculation, analysis, and access to sufficiently privileged users. Additionally, the backend db is huge, so I was also hoping to speed up the public experience by minimizing calls to the giant db. Making it happen is not the problem; everything is working as it should. Eventually I hope to divide the backend and front end into sub domains, and communicate by curling the backend to get an XML response.

I've read a lot of threads here about connecting to multiple MySQL databases in a single application, and most advise against without any technical reasoning for the opinion. I don't have any formal training in database architecture or web security, so I was hoping someone could explain to me why it's a bad idea to connect to multiple databases inside a single application. And if it is a big no-no, what is the best alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's been a long time since I asked this question, and while it's vague and misguided, it recently earned an upvote. So maybe novices like silly May '12 dyelawn will have the same curiosity.

There are no *general* positives or negatives to using multiple database connections in an application, it is always a *case-specific* issue. I think a lot of the misunderstanding for beginners stems from using WordPress or something similar that is entirely tied to a single, global connection. There are tons of reasons that you might need access to different databases within an application; that's why ORMs like Doctrine and Propel (yeah, I know, I'm Symfony-biased) make it so easy to configure multiple connections within an application.

If someone--who is only familiar with MySQL and global databased--is truly interested in learning about database architecture and the applications of different database engines, s/he should read about NoSQL. The s/he should dream up a use case where some portions of an application require the reliability, strict definitions, and relational capabilities of MySQL, while others would benefit from the speed and simplicity of `key=>value` pairing without necessarily needing to maintain ACID.

In short, a database is not the application, and an application should not be tied tightly to "the database".

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is advantage and also disadvantage there to use multiple db in single application...

the best thing is that your security is high when you use multiple database..

and the worst thing is that you have to manage both, so if any mistake there then it is big difficulty to solve this.